# Help with this exercise from Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to solve this question from Hungerford's book:

[image]

The lemma 6.11  says

[image]

Let $T$ be the subgroup of index $2$, if it generates $A_n$, then $A_n\subset T$, thus by Lagrange theorem: $[S_n:A_n]|A_n|=[S_n:T]|T|$, which implies $|A_n|=|T|$, so $A_n=T$ (why formally? pigeonhole principal?)

So the solution follows easily using the hint, but I couldn't prove why every subgroup of index $2$ must contain all $3$-cycles of $S_n$. What I know is every $3$-cycle has order $3$ and I'm trying to find something using this fact and the Lagrange theorem, without any success.

I need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hints: (1) Any subgroup of index $\;2\;$ in **any** group is normal in that group, and (2) **all** the cycles of the same length are in the same conjugation class, in particular all the $\;3$-cycles...

Comment: Along the same lines as DonAntonio, any index $2$ subgroup is normal.  This induces a map from the quotient to $\mathbb{Z}/2$.  The image of a $3$-cycle has to be trivial or have order $2$.  But, it can't have order $2$.

Comment: Ok, what Joe's said is more than half the proof of: permutations of the same cycle type remain conjugated in $\;A_n\;$ iff either it contains a cycle of even length **or** there are two different cycles of the same length.  Now note that a $\;3$-cycles has a *complete* cycle decomposition of the form $\;(abc)(d)(e)\;$ , with two $\;1$-cycles and, thus, all the three cycles remain one single conjugacy class in $\;A_5\;$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 you said " This induces a map from the quotient to Z/2", which quotient?

Comment: @user42912 The quotient of $S_n$ by the subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 let's say $\overline\sigma$ is the residue class of $\sigma$ and $\sigma$ is a 3-cycle, why $\overline\sigma$ can't have order $2$ in $S_n/T$?

Comment: @user42912 Call the quotient map $\pi$, then $\pi(\sigma^3)=e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose any $3$-cycle $\alpha \in S_n$. We want to show that $\alpha \in T$. To see this, we argue by contradiction. Suppose instead that $\alpha \notin T$. Then since $T$ has index $2$, we know that $S_n = T \cup \alpha T$ with $T \cap \alpha T = \emptyset$. Now consider the element $\alpha^2 \in S_n = T \cup \alpha T$. It can only land in two places:

- **Case 1:** Suppose that $\alpha^2 \in T$. Then since $\alpha$ has order $3$, we know that $\alpha^{-1} = \alpha^2 \in T$. But groups are closed under inverses, so $\alpha = (\alpha^{-1})^{-1} \in T$, a contradiction.
- **Case 2:** Suppose that $\alpha^2 \in \alpha T$. Then there is some $\beta \in T$ such that $\alpha^2 = \alpha\beta$. But then left cancellation by $\alpha$ gives us that $\alpha = \beta \in T$, a contradiction.

Thus, we conclude that $T$ contains all $3$-cycles of $S_n$, as desired. $~~~\blacksquare$